# Adding cell comments from raw xml for Excel 2007 using java

Tags: java, xlsx, xml-comments

I need to create cell comments for existing excel file by extracting the xlsx file and using raw XML file.

Is it possible to do it in java without using Apache poi library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't know much about excel but I found this [website](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/excel2007/excel2007s2p10.html) that might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i am actually expecting is the different xml files that are needed for creating comments and its relationship.I can't able to find document regarding this

Comment: @user3184747 ahh okay. HOpefilly you get it.